# Excel is not able to connect to Analysis server 2016. Error : No such host is known

Tags: sql, excel, excel-2010, ssas, olap

I am trying to connect to Analysis Server 2016 from Excel and I have Administrator permission on the Analysis Server. When I am trying to connect it on excel I am getting an error which says:

> The following system error occurred: No such host is known..'

Can anyone help me, please ? I tried to search for solutions but couldn't find anything.

Comment: its hard to say without knowing your network set up. make sure you can at least ping the server where the cube is sitting from your machine. Then make sure your Datasource is correctly set up

Comment: All other users are able to connect and I have same permission as they do.

Comment: it could be that your machine is sitting in a different domain than the SSAS server. But I'm just guessing here without knowing your Network.